# How can I print over network again?

Tags: printing

I used to be able to print over the network, but then one day I received this message:

```
/usr/lib/cups/backend/lpd failed
```

This is a printer that I installed myself through the **Administration>Printing** (Lucid 10.04 Gnome UI).

From the shell, it looks good:

```
$ lpq
Xerox is ready
no entries
```

Here are the last few lines of the error log:

```
$ cat /var/log/cups/error_log
D [28/Feb/2013:14:07:11 -0800] [Job 472] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [28/Feb/2013:14:07:11 -0800] [Job 472] Looking up "cups-server.linfield.edu"...`
D [28/Feb/2013:14:07:11 -0800] [Job 472] Connecting to cups-server.linfield.edu:515 for printer 
D [28/Feb/2013:14:07:11 -0800] [Job 472] Connecting to printer...
D [28/Feb/2013:14:07:11 -0800] [Job 472] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [28/Feb/2013:14:07:11 -0800] [Job 472] Connected to printer...
D [28/Feb/2013:14:07:11 -0800] [Job 472] Connected to 10.171.255.15:515 (IPv4) (local port 1023)...
D [28/Feb/2013:14:07:11 -0800] [Job 472] lpd_command 02 
D [28/Feb/2013:14:07:11 -0800] [Job 472] Sending command string (2 bytes)...
D [28/Feb/2013:14:07:11 -0800] [Job 472] Reading command status...
D [28/Feb/2013:14:07:11 -0800] [Job 472] lpd_command returning 1
D [28/Feb/2013:14:07:11 -0800] [Job 472] Backend returned status 1 (failed)
D [28/Feb/2013:14:07:11 -0800] [Job 472] End of messages
D [28/Feb/2013:14:07:11 -0800] [Job 472] printer-state=3(idle)
D [28/Feb/2013:14:07:11 -0800] [Job 472] printer-state-message="/usr/lib/cups/backend/lpd failed"
D [28/Feb/2013:14:07:11 -0800] [Job 472] printer-state-reasons=none
```

I am at a loss for what to do now.  I have tried these things:

- deleted the printer and reinstalled it
- turned the printer off and on
- stopped and restarted cups

Any ideas?  Is this something that has to be fixed at the System Administrator level?

Comment: In a matter of weeks Ubuntu 10.04 will be considered off topic in this forum as support ends in April assuming you are not running the Server edition. I would suggest a full backup and a clean install of either Ubuntu 12.04 or Xubuntu 12.04.  I'm recommending the LTS versions because they are supported for longer.  Try them both from a live CD/DVD or USB stick. Then install the one you prefer. If you still can't get printing to work let us know.

Comment: I would have upgraded to Precise Pangolin by now, but I like the Gnome desktop.

Comment: You don't have to use Unity.  You can try Ubuntu with the Gnome Classic Desktop [see here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/gnome-classic-in-ubuntu-12-04-its-like-nothing-ever-changed) To install it `sudo apt-get install gnome-panel`  I don't like Unity either -- I use it "Gnome Classic".

Comment: There is more information in this question[How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic-desktop)

Comment: can you type the ip address in the browser, check what it says? it may say device not attached.

Comment: When a device is not connected to a network or is not accessible, it's very rare for any useful message to be shown when attempting to access it with a web browser. Furthermore, unless the device runs a web server, the message you see will often (not always) be the same regardless of whether or no it is attached.